# how to Select current time without scrolling picker view

Tags: swift, datepicker

I am not able to select current time without scrolling picker view .

I am doing this -:

```
@objc func dateChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker?) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        if let date = sender?.date {
            reminderLbl.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
           }
}
```

this is for open picker view -:

```
 func openDatePickerView(){
    datePicker = UIDatePicker.init()
    datePicker.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
    if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
    self.view.addSubview(datePicker)
    toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 50))
    toolBar.barStyle = .default
    toolBar.items = [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil), UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.onDoneButtonClick))]
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    self.view.addSubview(toolBar)
}
```

Comment: You're probably calling this func for `valueChanged` event, it's not going to be called at the first time. Call the method in viewDidLoad.

Comment: it happens every time when we select current time

Comment: how you're selecting the current time?? Include relevant code and explain the problem then.

Comment: Call `dateChanged(datePicker)` method again at the end of `openDatePickerView`, this will populate the textfield initially with the current date.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Aren't you just missing `datePicker.setDate(Date(), animated: false)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attached the function that give you current time.

```
func getTimeFrom(date: Date) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    let time = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    lbl_Time.text = time
}
```

-> Call above function in **ViewDidLoad()** and pass current date from picker like below code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getTimeFrom(date: datePicker.date)
}
```

-> For Selected date and time from date picker.

```
@IBAction func actionPicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    getTimeFrom(date: sender.date)
}
```